# Does $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ for all $x$ imply normality for real Hilbert spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

The proof for complex Hilbert spaces crucially relies on the fact that $\langle Sx,x\rangle=\langle Tx,x\rangle$ for all x implies that S=T. This fact fails in the case of real Hilbert spaces as early as $\mathbb{R}^2$: let $S$ be rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $T$ be rotation by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Is there a proof that $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ for all $x$ implies $T^*T=TT^*$ which doesn't rely on this fact?

Comment: The problem is that fact isn't sufficient to show T*T-TT*=0 in the case of real hilbert spaces, as stated in the question. Some additional cleverness is required.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to reply to my own questions when I answer it myself, but here's a solution using the polarization identity for real spaces: for an arbitrary $x,y\in H$,
$$\langle Tx,Ty \rangle=\frac{1}{4}(||Tx+Ty||^2-||Tx-Ty||^2).$$
Apply linearity of $T$ and $T^*$ and the $||T(x-y)||=||T^*(x-y)||$ hypothesis to yield
$$\langle Tx,Ty \rangle=\frac{1}{4}(||T^*x+T^*y||^2-||T^*x-T^*y||^2)=\langle T^*x, T^*y\rangle.$$
Then
$$\langle T^*Tx,y \rangle=\langle T^*Tx,y \rangle,$$
and since $x,y$ are arbitrary, $T^*T=TT^*$.

Comment: why do you put limits there?

Comment: Thanks for the fix.